# Spring-boot: mongoDB date comparison not working

Tags: mongodb, date, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to get appointments for a particular date.

So I am passing `fromDate` and `toDate` to find data in that date range.

Here is my code, in which query method is changing the actual date passing to it.

I have also pasted the query formed by this code in **spring boot**.

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'");

fromDate = "2017-10-06T00:00:00.000Z";
toDate = "2017-10-07T23:00:00.000Z";        

Date startDate,endDate;

startDate = dateFormatter.parse(fromDate);
endDate = dateFormatter.parse(toDate);

System.out.println(startDate);
System.out.println(endDate);

Query q = new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(
          new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("fromDate").gte(startDate),
          Criteria.where("fromDate").lte(endDate)),
          new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("toDate").gte(startDate),
          Criteria.where("toDate").lte(endDate))
        ));

System.out.println(startDate);
System.out.println(endDate);

System.out.println(q); //here in query m getting different date

List<Appointment> result= mongoTemplate.find(q, Appointment.class);

System.out.println(result);
```

When I am trying to print query, it prints the following json which is wrong:

```
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "fromDate": {
                        "$gte": {
                            "$date": "2017-10-05T18:30:00.000Z"  //expected date 2017-10-06
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "fromDate": {
                        "$lte": {
                            "$date": "2017-10-07T17:30:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "toDate": {
                        "$gte": {
                            "$date": "2017-10-05T18:30:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "toDate": {
                        "$lte": {
                            "$date": "2017-10-07T17:30:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My expected date were "2017-10-06T00:00:00.000Z" and "2017-10-07T23:00:00.000Z".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the timezone to UTC when using `DateFormat` to parse string dates.

Alternatively you can use `Instant` in Java 8.

I have shown both examples.

`endDate` using `dateFormatter` with timezone set to `UTC`

`startDate` using `Instant`

Something like

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'");
dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date startDate,endDate;

startDate =  Date.from(Instant.parse("2017-10-06T00:00:00.000Z"));
endDate = dateFormatter.parse("2017-10-07T23:00:00.000Z");
```