# :Spring data is able to fetch data between 2 dates but not same date different times of same date

Tags: mongodb, date-range

Query to fetch records for time range of 10 seconds is fetched properly in mongo shell using below:

```
db.getCollection('collection-name').find({"@timestamp":{"$gte": ISODate("2018-02-07T01:51:45.005Z"),"$lt": ISODate("2018-02-07T01:51:55.005Z")}});
```

But in spring-data-mongodb I am unable to get the data using below methods. Either I am not able to define `ISODate("String value")` or `new Date("String value")` in `@Query` annotation or mongo query criteria.

Method 1: Mongo Repository & Query

```
@Query("{'@timestamp' :{'$gte':?0, '$lt':?1}}")
public List<collection-name> findByTimestamp( Date date,Date newdate);
```

Method 2: Using Mongo Query with criteria

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("@timestamp").gte( date).lt(newdate));
```

where date and new date fields are:

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'");
Date date = df.parse("2018-02-07T01:51:45.005Z");
Date newdate = df.parse("2018-02-07T01:51:55.005Z");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-boot: mongoDB date comparison not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674501/spring-boot-mongodb-date-comparison-not-working)